# Installing Ubuntu along side Win 10 on a Lenovo machine with an actual RAID 1 setup

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, system-installation, lenovo, raid

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo P73 with two SSDs configured in the BIOS as a RAID-1 (mirrored) array.

The Ubuntu installer doesn't recognize the drive, and some research showed that this seems to be a pretty well known issue.

The problem is that *every* solution I saw (and I checked a lot) assumes a *single* SSD configured in RAID mode and presents switching that drive to AHCI mode as a solution.

However, I have an actual, multi-drive RAID-1 setup and I'm not really sure how to proceed.

Is it possible to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (or even 19.10) alongside Win 10 on a system with an existing, dual SSD, RAID-1 setup?

Comment: Have you checked https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ThinkWiki? It's focused on the thinkpad models, but it's a great resource for Linux on Lenovo machines. There might be something useful there.

Comment: @terdon I haven't! Checking now, will post back if I find anything useful. Thanks.

Comment: @terdon No dice, I think. I searched as best I could and went through any article that mentioned Ubuntu or RAID, browsed through the Ubuntu page list, and generally poked around and looked for hints, but there's not a lot of recent info and I couldn't find anything about Ubuntu on RAID setups, even older versions. :/

Comment: I am afraid, that it will be difficult to install Ubuntu into a system where you have Windows and RAID occupying all drives (and want to keep them). But I think the computer is powerful enough, so you can install VirtualBox into Windows, create a virtual machine and install Ubuntu into the virtual machine.

Comment: @sudodus That's a good idea. Yeah, this configuration has a lot of horsepower, it should be fine. I think that's what I'm going to do for now just to get me up and running at least. I'll continue to research this, too, though. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck @JasonC :-)